# Is there a better way to rotate the order of vertices of currently selected faces in edit mode?

Tags: scripting, bmesh

I've been playing with duplifaces and it turns out the orientation of the copied geometry depends on the order of the vertices in the face (https://developer.blender.org/T30547).  Since I'm unhappy with the orientation of some of my duplicated geometry, clearly I need to "rotate" the vertex order of some of the faces.

I've come up with this little python snippet, but it has one drawback I can think of.

```
# rotate selected face

import bpy
import bmesh

mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

for face in bm.faces:
    if (face.select):
        vs = face.verts[:]
        vs2 = vs[1:]+vs[:1]
        # face.verts =vs2 # fails because verts is read-only
        bm.faces.remove(face)
        f2 = bm.faces.new(vs2)
        f2.select = True

# trigger UI update    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

The drawback is that it destroys the old face and creates a new one.  I suspect that there will be some cases where information on the old face will be lost.

Just for some flavor, here's an illustration of a situation where you might want manual control over the orientation: [image]

Comment: JA12 put together [a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diI8xJ9oo_8) that illustrates some workflow techniques to control this if you are building new geometry:

Comment: There is a tool to help re-order mesh elements, which can be accessed in the GUI with `Space` *> Sort Mesh elements* (you must be in edit mode), or in python with [`bpy.ops.mesh.sort_elements()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.sort_elements). Unfortunately it didn't seem to affect duplifaces, at least it didn't when I tried it..

Comment: Even if Sort Mesh Elements were to affect the vertex order on a face, there's only a 1/4 chance that the order of the vertices is the order you want.  I think it would require a new operator, but I'm disinclined to start work on a new patch until my other patch gets accepted, or even rejected.

Comment: Do you actually want to rotate the faces, or do you want to flip the normals (so the orientation the polygon is facing)? There are `bmesh.utils.face_flip()`, `bmesh.ops.rotate_edges()` and `bmesh.utils.edge_rotate()`, which might do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The UI isn't updating because the script does not call

```
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

(I got this from [how to use BMesh to add verts, faces, and edges to existing geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/414/how-to-use-bmesh-to-add-verts-faces-and-edges-to-existing-geometry?rq=1) )