# In python, how to construct a line in a plane parallel to the XZ plane, at a particular angle to the XY plane, and a particular length

Tags: python, geometry

For example, let's say I want to construct a line from (0,0,0), to a point within the XZ plane, at an angle of 23 degrees, and with a length of 10. The endpoint would then be (10cos(23deg),0,10sin(23deg)) or something like that.

1. Is there a way to construct a line given these endpoints?
2. More convenient would be a way to construct a line given the origin point and an XZ vector, is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

**Use Vectors.**

The `mathutils` module has a number of  classes and methods to deal with linear algebra requirements. See `mathutils.geometry` for methods to find intersections and closest points of points, lines and planes. (*Maybe handy re other question*)

Blender comes with a python console,  used below to demonstrate one way to construct the  vector  in question,

Start with  the X axis as a basis vector

```
>>> x_axis = Vector((1, 0, 0))
```

Next make a matrix to  rotate it around the Y axis to obtain any vector on XY plane, going thru (0, 0, 0).

```
>>> R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(23), 4, 'Y')
>>> v  = (R @ x_axis).normalized()
>>> v
Vector((0.9205049276351929, 0.0, -0.39073100686073303))
```

No need to normalize since the rotated unit vector will maintain its unit length.

Testing result with simple trig

```
>>> degrees(acos(v.x))
22.99998912203489
```

Notice that rotating around Y axis (looking down the axis) rotates clockwise and moves into negative quadrant.  Negate either angle or axis  `((0, -1, 0))` when constructing rotation matrix to screw the other way.

```
>>> degrees(asin(v.z))
-22.999992429369787
```

Angle between x axis and v

```
>>> degrees(x_axis.angle(v))
22.999989256384694
```

Note can get a signed angle using 2D vectors. *eg* only the XZ components

```
>>> degrees(v.xz.angle_signed(x_axis.xz))
-22.999992671479276
```

To make the vector length `d` multiply it by the scalar

```
v *= d
```

**Make a line.**

To make an edge from origin to v, it would have vert coordinates

```
verts = (
    (0, 0, 0),
    v,
    )
```

And edges (indexing verts)

```
edges = (
    (0, 1),
    )
```

which can be fed into `bpy.types.Mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)`  Eg make a new single edge mesh named "Line"

```
>>> me = D.meshes.new("Line")
>>> me.from_pydata(verts, edges, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's all understandable! But, I entered it all into the console and no errors came back, but no object was created on my screen, either. Then I tried entering the first line into the text editor (after import bpy and import mathutils), and got the error, "python script failed..." when I ran it. No message appeared in the system console.

Comment: It's a mesh datablock, not an object. Make an object and  Link the mesh to an object.  `ob = D.objects.new("Line", me)`

Comment: Still no line on the screen, no object in the scene collection.

Comment: C'mon mate, then link the object to a scene collection. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159185/15543

Comment: "C'mon mate" sounds like maybe I'm being impossibly dense. I should probably read a good book on python in blender before trying any of this stuff. I just figured 40 plus years of programming in various languages might help. Guess not. Here's my trouble what's a scene? a collection? a mesh (it's really a datablock, right?) a datablock--specifically? a context? What's an object (I know what it is in C++, but that's not it, is it)? Can you recommend a good, terse, complete, explanatory reference, something akin to The Waite Group's C Bible? PS I'm using Blender 2.83 for the stability.

Comment: PS With help from your last hint, I got my line on the screen -- thanks!