# Python to create just vertices not faces and edges

Tags: python, mesh, vertices

This: [create mesh then add vertices to it in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61879/create-mesh-then-add-vertices-to-it-in-python) (see snippet below) used `mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)`.

I would like to just create a mesh of vertices, no edges, no faces.

I would think I would delete:

```
edges = []
faces = [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

But what would I replace `mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)` with?

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("myBeautifulMesh")  # add the new mesh
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
col.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

verts = [( 1.0,  1.0,  0.0), 
         ( 1.0, -1.0,  0.0),
         (-1.0, -1.0,  0.0),
         (-1.0,  1.0,  0.0),
         ]  # 4 verts made with XYZ coords
edges = []
faces = [[0, 1, 2, 3]]

mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
```

Comment: mesh.from_pydata(verts, [ ] , [ ] )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (edited to add - I just tried it, it works):

```
vertices = [( 1.0,  1.0,  0.0), 
            ( 1.0, -1.0,  0.0),
            (-1.0, -1.0,  0.0),
            (-1.0,  1.0,  0.0),
           ]
edges = []
faces = []
new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('new_mesh')
new_mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
```

See [How to create mesh through the Blender Python API](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-create-mesh-through-the-blender-python-api/), which describes how to create a mesh of just a vertex, no edges or faces.