# Using Python to add object with specified number of vertices?

Tags: python, mesh, vertices

How, in Python, could I add an object with a specified number of vertices *n*, all of which are at, say, the origin (0,0,0)?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/414/how-to-use-bmesh-to-add-verts-faces-and-edges-to-existing-geometry?rq=1 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh/2416#2416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to position your cursor at the origin (0,0,0)
2. Follow [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61893/2517) to create a mesh with a certain number of vertices