# With Python, how do I add data to an existing mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

Let's say I create an object with the GUI. Its mesh is called "Cube.001" and has 8 vertices.

How do I now add - for example - a 9th vertex at position `[3,3,3]` to this mesh? Same question for faces and edges. Same question for non-bmesh and bmesh.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/414/how-to-use-bmesh-to-add-verts-faces-and-edges-to-existing-geometry https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos These two 9-year old questions are outdated and do not answer my question.

Comment: @Claus: did u try out the answers or did u just look at the dates of the answers? i just tried out this link https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/414/how-to-use-bmesh-to-add-verts-faces-and-edges-to-existing-geometry and i could copy and paste it and it works like a charm....and the answer does add vertices, faces and edges. But yeah, it does not add a position 3,3,3 as the 9th vertex, but maybe you should take a deeper look at it and learn from it.

Comment: Yep, tested just now and it works.

Comment: I'd like to know without using bmesh.

Comment: @Claus I updated the answer : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2408/86891 It should work in recent versions.